# Pulling only Registration Contact information on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am not using real-time asterisk , But still astdb.sqlite3  contains entries of online peers with Reg.Contact information  in SIP/registry/peer.   key . I would like to store contact information of all peers as they come online  in a separate persistent database. I need this for sending push notifications by fetching deviceID etc information in registration contact .

I tried to pull this information from astdb.sqlite3 but the entries are clearing off as soon as devices go offline .Though  I am able to  fetch the information with `"sip show peer XXXX"` in asterisk CLI , It is overburdened to fetch every time like this . Instead I want to save only Regcontact information for all the devices in a database ( without realtime) as the devices come online.  The other way I tried to pull the information is using AMI event listener. But with AMI I  don't see complete information like contact information  It displays only below information

```
Event: PeerStatus
Privilege: system,all
SequenceNumber: 75
File: manager.c
Line: 1856
Func: manager_default_msg_cb
ChannelType: SIP
Peer: SIP/2030
PeerStatus: Reachable
```

Can someone suggest a better way to push Only Regcontact information to a database as the devices come online .

Answer (score 0):

There are no mechanism like that in asterisk.

You can use kamailio or write patch similar to this one https://reviewboard.asterisk.org/r/4490/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have dynamic IPs for your endpoints, and you want a way to update a separate DB as soon as a device registers with an IP/port pair.

If you enable the security log, you will see all auth events, including the "SuccessfulAuth" event, which includes the RemoteAddress of the endpoint (including port and protocol).

Here is an example line:

```
[Jul 21 19:53:45] SECURITY[1342] res_security_log.c: SecurityEvent="SuccessfulAuth",EventTV="2020-07-21T19:53:45.182+0000",Severity="Informational",Service="SIP",EventVersion="1",AccountID="102",SessionID="0x7f41040132c0",LocalAddress="IPV4/UDP/10.0.0.200/5060",RemoteAddress="IPV4/UDP/10.0.0.75/5062",UsingPassword="1"
```

If all you're looking for is `AccountID="102"` and `RemoteAddress="IPV4/UDP/10.0.0.75/5062"`, a very fast/cheap way to get it is to enable the security log, and use a script to tail it and update your DB as soon as the event occurs. I like to keep the security log on anyways for utilities like fail2ban. Just make sure your script is able to reopen the file each time it is rotated.

**Edit:**
By default the log is in /var/log/asterisk. To enable it, edit /etc/asterisk/logger.conf and un-comment (or create) the line under `[logfiles]` that says `security => security`.